# Python Windows: How to visualize a Keras model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

Is there any way to visualize a model in Keras and print all of the weights and biases to the picture? I am thinking of something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkCgV.jpg) but I can't find anything that seems to work. It is hard to install Graphviz on my windows computer so it is hard to get the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/visualization/) to work.

Comment: Do you need to visualize only the architecture?. How big is the network you want to visualize?, usually the number of parameters is quite big, so visualizing them is not very common.

Comment: By the way the research gate link you posted seems to be broken.

Comment: @bones.felipe well if I could even visualize something small, like 5 layers with 20 notes per layer then that would be very helpful. Also, I have changed the link.